# Expressions that mean "same thing"

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I'm looking for some expressions that mean "same thing" or "same difference". Can you guys post some?

Comment: Can you please add a sample sentence where you would use the expressionypu are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are loads! For starters...

> Much of a muchness

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/much_of_a_muchness

> Not a hair's breadth between them

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+hair%27s+breadth

> Six and half a dozen

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/six_of_one,_half_a_dozen_of_the_other

> Eachy peachy

http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/sndns1336 ... I'd use that one to mean 'same difference', but not according to the link. Let's set a new trend with it! ;)

> [They're] like peas in a pod

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-two-peas-in-a-pod

And there's one that I can't remember. If I may be so bold as to include a question in an answer, can anybody complete this for me:

> Same ____, different ____ ?

(where the *different* thing is clearly utterly insubstantial)

Answer (score 1):

Two sides of the same coin

be cut from the same cloth

be in the same boat

be cast in the same mould

painted with the same brush